# Can not get height value using underscore throttle Vue.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, vue.js

i just want to get height value every `second` i put in second parameter in `_.throttle()` using vue.js but doesn't work :(

Here my vue code:

```
import underscore from 'underscore';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            progress: 0,
            height: 0,
            scroll: 0
        }
    },

    created() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(this.handleScroll, 300));
    },

    methods: {
        /**
         * Handle the scroll.
         */
        handleScroll() {
            this.height = _.throttle(document.getElementById('tags-module').offsetTop, 300);
            this.scroll = window.scrollY;

            this.progress = Math.floor((this.scroll/this.height)*100);
        }
    }
}
```

There in `handleScroll()` method, `this.height` i used throttle but in can't get the `height` value. and if i remove the `throttle`, works fine.

Please tell me where's my mistake.

Comment: Throttle returns a function, not a value. Wrap handleScroll in throttle.

Comment: then how to return value?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
methods:{
    handleScroll: _.throttle(function(){
        this.scroll = window.scrollY;
        this.progress = Math.floor((this.scroll/this.height)*100);
    }, 300),
    updateHeight: _.throttle(function(){
        this.height = document.getElementById('tags-module').offsetTop;
    }, 1000)

},
created(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        this.updateHeight();
        this.handleScroll();
    });
}
```

Comment: nope, `handleScroll` throttle and `height` throttle is different.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `handleScroll` method is already throttled, you don't need a second one. However, if you wish to keep it, you need to return the value:

```
this.height = _.throttle(
  () => document.getElementById('tags-module').offsetTop,
  300
)()
```

From [the manual](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle):

> Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function, that, when invoked repeatedly, will only actually call the original function at most once per every wait milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with.

Comment: i just need the height value.

Comment: @motanelu `this.height` still returns a function.

Comment: Sorry, typo. You need to call the function returned by `throttle()`

Comment: That's just going to create a new function and execute it immediately every time.